# Good place to check your domain name information and have it orginized

Tags: domain-name-system, domain-name, whois

I have a lot of domain names at different registrars. I often work with these domains and change the information on them such as nameservers and contact details.

Often times I need to check what the details on the domain names are and I use different websites to do that.

For example for nameserver check and overal heath of the domain I use http://intodns.com or http://dnssy.com/

For the contact information etc I use http://whois.net or some other ransom tool I can find.

Now I am looking for a place where I can register, and add all the domain names I own, and can click on them and view the whois information and the dns details etc.

My domain names are spread over different registrars, and different hosting companies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Shameless self-promotion.*

I'm working on a startup called RoboDomain which aims to solve exactly this problem.
Please give it a try and let me know if it works for you: [www.robodomain.com](http://www.robodomain.com/)

Comment: Nice service man, great interface also.

Comment: Thanks Saif. Feel free to contact me if you have any feedback.

Comment: Hi, I have been using your service for over a year now for all my domains. Works really great, the website has a nice and stable feel to it, and the options are great. I am pleased. Only problem I am facing is that I get no info for .nl (Netherlands) domain names. Any chance this could be implemented? Even without it, great work!

Comment: Hi @SaifBechan. Thanks for your comment. I encourage you to open a ticket at http://support.robodomain.com/ or send an email to support@robodomain.com